# reload class with dynamic mixin in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, code-caching

i have following model

```
class Chicken < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize :grow_up

  def grow_up
    if gender == "female"
      self.class.send(:include, Hen)
    elsif gender == "male"
      self.class.send(:include, Rooster)
    end
  end

end

module Hen

   def communicate
     "cluck cluck!"
   end

end

module Rooster

   def communicate
     "cock-a-doodle-doo!"
   end

end
```

However, while running rspec tests, after first Chicken is initialized with gender, communicate method becomes cached and all Chicken say the same independently of their gender, even though cache_classes is set to false in config/environments/test.rb

How can I reload Chicken class during tests execution or modify this code to remove this problem?

Comment: You're sending it to the class, whereas you really only want to send it to instances.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to switch to single table inheritance instead (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance), which will hopefully solve this problem.